# Is the Y connection advantageous for power supply?

Tags: delta

I have heard that 'Y' connection is advantageous for the three phase supply and '∆' for the three phase load e.g. a motor.

Please tell me if this is correct and if so why.

Comment: The assumption is that you are referring to 3 phase mains power.  I think you need to elaborate on the loads you are referring to as connecting someone to 3phase mains is not going to have a good outcome.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: He said that in terms of using electricity regardless of the purpose, delta connection makes the coil thinner and cheaper. Conversely, in terms of supplying electricity, the Y connection is said to be economical.

Answer (score 1):

For a generator, if you are going to power any single phase loads, then you **need** a neutral, which is provided by the 'Y' connection. If you are only going to power three phase loads, then either will do.

As a motor is balanced three phase load, there is no need for a neutral, so either configuration will do.

There is no advantage to either configuration in terms of power. If you want to make an electrical machine, whether motor, generator or transformer, to have a power handling of x number of watts at y temperature rise, then it doesn't matter whether it's 'Y' or '∆' configured, it will use the same active weight of copper and iron.

There are incidental differences. For the same windings (thickness, number of turns), a Y configuration will have a higher voltage and lower current on the phases than a ∆. If you can match the voltages in your particular situation without having to use a transformer, then that's a big bonus.

A trick employed by users of big three phase motors was to start them in 'Y', before running them in '∆', which reduced the starting current surge somewhat, without needing any more equipment than a switch.

Comment: Are you correct that there is no advantage other than being able to start Y-Delta when the load is Delta connected?

Comment: @wooyoungkim Of course I'm correct, I would not have said it otherwise. Perhaps link to the source of your misiniformation, 'I have heard' is not easy to understand what the context was. There may be incidental advantages to Y or delta, like availability of particular equipment, or wires sizes, but there are no fundamental power advantages, N kW costs the same whether it's from a Y or delta machine. Sometimes you need a neutral out of your generator, and so must have it Y connected, or need to add on an expensive delta-Y transformer. Y-delta starting is old school, use VFDs now, much better.

Comment: The information is the story you hear from your company boss.
He told me that if the motor has the same output, the delta connection (or Y connection if it is a transformer) makes the coil thinner.

Comment: @wooyoungkim Your choice. Do you want to believe someone who knows how to run companies, or someone who understands physics and can tell you **why** the same rating will need the same amount of copper? It's possible that the question has been misunderstood going form him to you to him to me to wherever, so it's worth going back to him and asking precisely what he's keeping constant. Keeping some things constant will result in thinner wire, but they are not fundamental things like power, they are secondary things like voltage.